# How do I control the layout when using setToolbarItems?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to add 2 `UIBarButtonItem`s to the bottom toolbar programmatically from the `UIViewController`. Right now I'm creating the buttons, adding them to a `NSArray`, and then calling `[self setToolbarItems:buttonArray animated:YES]`. This adds the buttons to the bottom left hand corner of the toolbar, right next to each other. What I want to do is add one button the bottom left of the toolbar and the other button to the bottom right. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your toolBarItems should look something like that:

```
UIBarButtonItem *firstButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:self action:@selector(someSelector)];
UIBarButtonItem *secondButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(someSelector)];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstButton, flexibleSpace, secondButton,nil];

[firstButton release], [secondButton release], [flexibleSpace release];
```

This will give you something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the bar button system item `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace`

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftButton; // set that
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton; // set that

NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftButton, flexibleSpace, rightButton, nil];
[toolbar setItems:items];

[flexibleSpace release];
// release the other two if necessary
```

You can also use the bar button system item `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace` if you wish to manually control the spacing by setting the width property on it.

Comment: I have such items for my first and last items and iOS doesn't refresh the toolbar items layout on a rotation

Answer (score 0):

You can add the system bar button item named `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` in between your buttons. It will push them to the sides.

Comment: I have such items for my first and last items and iOS doesn't refresh the toolbar items layout on a rotation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like iOS doesn't refresh the layout of toolbars on a device rotation if the toolbar items are added using code rather than defined in a Storyboard.

The solution is to add a `viewWillTransition` handler and set the VC's `toolbaritems` nil and then back to the bar button items desired.

```
// method within a UIViewController class

// set to nil so that iOS places buttons correctly on a rotation
tools = ... // an [UIBarButtonItem]
toolbarItems = nil
setToolbarItems(tools, animated: false)
```

If your toolbar was [FlexibleSpace] [UIBarButtonItem] [FlexibleSpace] then this handler would keep the `BarButtonItem` in the centre of its toolbar when a device was rotated.